# Make image overlap its parent view in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-view

what i want is to make image overlap top edge of its parent view. without fixating any of view sizes

[image 1 expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Q20.png)

i tried to use `Box` with image inside set to `.wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.Bottom, unbounded = true)`, but parent `Box` takes whole image inside itself.
i suppose parent box takes size of its biggest child, so image, as Box biggest child, can no longer be outside box frame
finally it looks like this

[image 2 actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fbHy.png)

my code looks like this

```
@Composable
fun ComponentViewOverhead(
    title: String,
    modifier: Modifier,
    subTitle: String,
    avatar: Avatar,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(
                gradient = GradientsDefault.pink,
                roundedCornerShape,
                gradientStyle = GradientStyle.Horizontal
            )
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = LocalIndication.current,
                role = Role.Button,
                onClick = onClick
            )
    ) {
        Row(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Column(
                modifier = modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .padding(
                        start = Theme.space.s16,
                        top = Theme.space.s16,
                        bottom = Theme.space.s16
                    ),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(Theme.space.s2)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = title,
                    style = Theme.typography.h5,
                    color = Theme.color.universal.white
                )
            }
            Avatar(
                model = Avatar,
                modifier = modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Bottom)
                    .wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.Bottom, unbounded = true)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Avatar(
    model: Avatar,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val painter = painterResource(id = model.iconResId)
    Image(
        modifier = modifier,
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = model.contentDescription
    )
}
```

Comment: I can help you with this. Can you clarify if the text has always half of the space of the row? Or is it variable. If the text is variable, do you want the image to shrink according to the available space?

Comment: You will need the `requiredSize` Modifier, check out this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78159479/how-to-align-a-bigger-child-within-a-smaller-parent-in-jetpack-compose/78160489#78160489
Unfortunately there is no answer yet.

Comment: @F.Mysir, hi 
text is variable. The image needs to be always outside the box, about 20dp out

Comment: @BenjyTec, i cannot use `requiredSize` cause image comes from server and i do not know the size